# Branding Setup Page and SLDS Tokens

Tags: lightning-design-system, slds, design-tokens, theme-branding

Is there a place or has someone documented which [SLDS Design Tokens that are marked "Themeable" Yes](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/design-tokens/) match up with what is presented on the "New Custom Theme" under the Themes and Branding Setup:

[image]